# How to show previously checked items when user opens a bottom sheet dialog again?

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-bottomsheetdialog

I have a bottom sheet dialog in which a listview with checkboxes are there. Now I want to filter some data based on checked items from that listview. I'm storing the ids of checked items in listview but when i open the bottom sheet dialog again the checked items shows unchecked but if i choose another item which is unchecked then the id of that particular item is added to the previous one.

So my question is how to show previously item checked in a listview if the user opens the bottom sheet dialog box again ? can you give some justification about it and how to do it in android through java code ?

Comment: You can check those checkboxes while you get STATE_EXAPANDING for bottom sheet

Comment: but I'm not using STATE_EXPANDING for bottom sheet, is there any other way to solve it ?

Comment: You can have callback of bottomsheet in your activity and in that you should check the state and then work accordingly